# Flutter webview - google map doesn't show

Tags: flutter, google-maps, webview

I have an application where I show a webview of my site.

Inside the screen shown in the webview there is a button in which, when clicked, a google map is shown (like a modal, it's not another screen).
The webview works correctly but when I click on the button the map is not shown.

I don't understand if the webview doesn't take the click or if there are map display problems.

Some idea?

PS: I have the same problem both on android and iOS

Comment: Hello. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue so that the community might be able to check and see what's wrong.

Comment: fixed: there was an "&" at the end of the url and for some reason this broke the rendering of the page in the web view